# Multiple Application Folders Priority?

Tags: applications, filesystem, macos

How are `Application` folders treated or considered on multiple volumes of OS X? Are they treated and indexed with equal priority as the root `/Applications`?

I my case I am considering putting the bulk of applications onto another hybrid drive with HFS+ so as to minimize the space used on my root SSD drive, but I want to make sure that things are resolved properly.  Otherwise I'll just be symlinking the folder onto the primary volume.

NOTE: One thing I have noticed here is that a number of apps ranging from Synergy to Screenflow are wanting to be in a on-filesystem (hardlinked) `/Applications` folder rather than allowing the folder to be softlinked.  It is not a frequent occurrence, but I've found 3 or 4 apps so far that are having these kinds of issues.

Comment: I don't know the actual answer to your question, but I'd say symlinking would be 'safest', just in case some apps really want to see their default path. I've never noticed it matter if I run an app from a different drive, any saved prefs etc will still go to the boot drive's structure; but it may be different if it thinks it's been 'deleted' from the boot drive & then appears somewhere else.

Comment: Well, I would normally agree, but I also get some odd issues.  For example (I've reported this to the developer), Synergy complains and wants to be installed in the /Applications folder when it is simply symlink'd over.  I am going to dig a bit more and move forward in the symlink direction as it is what I have done before, but I was hoping to know if anyone has more clarity on the matter of the OS's prioritization.